# Images of interval edge coloring

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, examples, graph-colorings

I found out the definition of interval edge colorings, concept put by Kamalian in various papers but could not find a graph depicting an example. Where can I find pictures of explicit examples of interval edge colorings of graphs? It is hard to get a clear picture of the concept without such examples.

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper by [P.A. Petrosyan: Interval edge-colorings of complete graphs and n-dimensional cubes](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X10000439) which contains some pictures of interval edge-colorings.

The key is that a vertex of degree $n$ has its (distinct) edge colors in a range $R=[a,\dots,b]$ with $b-a=n-1$.